# "There is no implicit reference conversion from 'object' to 'System.IEquatable<object>'."

Tags: c#, generics, iequatable

I got this error:

There is no implicit reference conversion from `object` to `System.IEquatable<object>`.

When I am tried to create Generic class

```
MyClass<T, V> where T : IEquatable<T>
```

with 'type parameter' as "object,object":

```
MyClass<object, object> mc = new MyClass<object, object>(t, t)
```

and constructor parameter `(t, t)` is the object of some other class (`Test t=new Test()`).

Class 'Test' having generic method with `IEquatable<T>` constraint:

```
public bool Equals<T, V>(T tp,V vp) where T : IEquatable<Test>
```

And the Generic class has

```
IEquatable<T>
```

constraint.

Comment: Could you please fix your formatting? As it stands, your question is barely readable.

Comment: As the error states, `object` does not implement `IEquatable<object>` so can't be used as the type parameter for `T`.

Comment: I have fixed your formatting but it's still pretty bad. Don't tell about your code, show it. Show a complete example.

Comment: "with 'type parameter' as "object":" - there are two type parameters.

Comment: If you want to use `object` you'll have to remove the constraint.  But really using `object` with generic classes kinda defeats the purpose of using generics in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You've indicated in your generic class signature that `T` must implement `IEquatable<T>` and then tried to use `object` as a type argument for `T`.

Which do you really want?  Do you want to enforce that `T` implements this interface?  Or do you want to use virtually any kind of class for `T`?

Use something other than `object` for the `T` type argument for the first case, or remove the constraint for the second.